# Bad performance on UITableView with UIWebView in cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a `UITableView` with `UIWebView` in cells.
Data I want to show is fetched from the web, stored in array and then shown through `UIWebView`. I have to use `WebView` as I have some MathJax that can only be hsow through it.

When I scroll through `UITableView`, I get *bad performance for a split of a second, when a `WebView` is loading HTML*.

Is there any way to fix this?

What crosses my mind is sope sort of pre-populating `webViews`, but Im not sure if it's possible. I haven't found anything usefoul on the web.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I didn't added code before, because this is a general question, and any `UITabelView` with a `UIWebView` in it will have this performance problem. But here it is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     SuperTraenerHistoryCell *cell = (SuperTraenerHistoryCell*)[tableView  
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SuperTraenerHistoryCell"];

    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray* nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SuperTraenerHistoryCell" owner:self 
options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell.answer loadHTMLString:myAnswer.answer_text baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:NSTemporaryDirectory()]];
}
```

SuperTraenerHistoryCell.h

```
@interface SuperTraenerHistoryCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *_answer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *correct;


@end
```

In the webView I show the data, and in `UIImageView` I show green or red sign, if the question was answered right or wrong.

Comment: I like how people act smart and downvote, without saying any real solution or critics. Keep it up !

Comment: add you code for reference, this will occurs in wrong cell identifier or wrong table view height calculation

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the `answer` property of your cell is a `WebView`, which is clearly not the most efficient way to display info in tableviewcell, since loading content is asynchronous.

If so, as your content seems to be offline in your app, try considering using NSAttributedText to display formatted text or split your content into `UIImageView` and `UILabel` which will be displayed faster.

Anyway, with such few information, it is hard to help you. Maybe if you edit your post and add the header of your `SuperTraenerHistoryCell` could be really helpful here.

Comment: I'll try with NSAttributedText first. Seems like a good tip...
And I have to keep webView because I have some MathJax, that needs to be displayed that way

Comment: Not much luck with NSAtributedText :(